# How do I use getters and setters for a variable of type array to access items of the array by index instead of the entire array itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
class SomeClass {
     var dates: [Date] {
          get {
               return ckRecord.object(forKey: "dates") as! [Date]
          }
          set(newDates) {
               ckRecord.setObject(newDates as! CKRecordValue, "dates")
          }
     }
}
```

In the previous code, how do I write code in the get and set closures to save to CloudKit and retrieve the data from CloudKit everytime I get one of the values from the array or set one of the values in the array, which means I don't retrieve the whole array or set the whole array, only one of the values at a given index as in the following code:

```
var obj = SomeClass()
obj.dates[0] = Date()
```

I don't have a problem using CloudKit. I have a problem figuring out how to arrange the code for the get and set closures so that I properly access the array from the CloudKit record by index. I am attempting to wrap the CloudKit record in class SomeClass.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you can't do that by implementing `get/set` for your property. But you can do that at least by two ways:

1) Extract logic of getter/setter in function:

```
func getDate(_ index: Int) -> Date?
func set(date: Date, index: Int)
```

This will work fine, but it looks ugly.

2) More swifty way is using the [`subscript`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html). In this case you create class, that holds private `dates` and this class allows you to access concrete date by using subscript. Simple example:

```
class Dates {

    private var dates: [Date] = []

    subscript(index: Int) -> Date? {
        get {
            guard dates.indices.contains(index) else { return nil }
            return dates[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            guard let date = newValue else { return }
            dates.insert(date, at: index)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum, it's just an example. I believe you can find more concrete info in vadian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is an extension of `CKRecord` with functions to insert, add and get a date by index and index subscription.

To modify the array you always have to get it from the record, change it and put it back.

```
extension CKRecord {

    func date(at index : Int) -> Date? {
        guard let dates = self["dates"] as? [Date], index < dates.count else { return nil }
        return dates[index]
    }

    func appendDate(_ date: Date) {
        guard var dates = self["dates"] as? [Date] else { return }
        dates.append(date)
        self["dates"] = dates as CKRecordValue
    }

    func insertDate(_ date : Date, at index: Int) {
        guard var dates = self["dates"] as? [Date], index <= dates.count else { return }
        dates.insert(date, at: index)
        self["dates"] = dates as CKRecordValue
    }

    public subscript(index: Int) -> Date? {
        get {
            guard let dates = self["dates"] as? [Date], index < dates.count else { return nil }
            return dates[index]
        }
        set {
            guard let newDate = newValue,
                var dates = self["dates"] as? [Date],
                dates.indices.contains(index) else { return }
            dates[index] = newDate
            self["dates"] = dates as CKRecordValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what would the syntax look like to access the dates and the CKRecord?

Comment: You can directly access the dates by index subscription (`record[0]`). If the record doesn't have a `dates` field it returns `nil`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you very much!